# mysql select statement that includes group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Ive a mysql statement like this

```
SELECT distinct mk.gene as gene, qs.rs as snp, CONCAT (qs.A1, qs.A2) as genotype
FROM dallas.QS_base qs  cross join   
dallas.staging mk 
     ON qs.rs = mk.rs 
WHERE qs.sampleID = 'mydna' 
order by gene ASC;
```

which returns this type of output

```
'ACE'    'RS4343',    'AA'
'ACTN3'  'RS1815739'  'TC'
```

from this type of table (dallas.staging)

```
'heart health', 'ACE', 'RS4343'
'skin health', 'ACE', 'RS4343'
'sports performance', 'ACE', 'RS4343'
'sports performance', 'ACTN3', 'RS1815739'
'longevity', 'ACTN3', 'RS1815739'
```

and this (dallas.QS_base)

```
'mydna','RS4343','A','A'
'mydna','RS1815739','T','C'
```

How should I change the mysql statement above to enable me to get this output? I believe I need to use group_concat command.

```
'ACE'    'RS4343',    'AA' '(heart health, sports performance, skin health)'
'ACTN3'  'RS1815739'  'TC' '(sports performance, longevity)'
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @luksch: please see edit (how should I change the mysql statement to give desired results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the job for you (note the distinct on mk.gene is not necessary as you are grouping by it):

```
SELECT mk.gene as gene, qs.rs as snp, CONCAT (qs.A1, qs.A2) as genotype, GROUP_CONCAT(mk.condition) AS conditions
FROM QS_base qs  cross join   
staging mk 
     ON qs.rs = mk.rs 
WHERE qs.sampleID = 'mydna'
group by gene
order by gene ASC;
```

Output:

```
gene    snp         genotype    conditions
ACE     RS4343      AA          heart health,sports performance,skin health
ACTN3   RS1815739   TC          sports performance,longevity
```

Comment: thanks, I did try the group_concat as a field definition already but it only returns a single row

Comment: actually the group by is what made it work - thanks!

Comment: Yes - if you use aggregation functions like GROUP_CONCAT without a GROUP BY you will get only one row as MySQL will just group all selected rows together.